# Should I upgrade to the latest unsupported kernel?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, kernel

I have been wondering about this for a while and a plain answer have been impossible to find. It is mainly about how the kernel is developed and maintained. I'm using Xubuntu 12.04 with kernel 3.2, and I'm aware of later LTS kernel versions.

I have a fairly new motherboard (ASUS M5A99FX Pro R2.0). Of course it was bundled with a set of Windows drivers, but the solution for Linux was far easier. It just said: Use the latest kernel.

The latest kernel when I bought it was 3.8, I think. (I don't know for sure the release date.) Obviously easy to solve then, or not! I could of course download and compile the vanilla kernel, or use the latest Ubuntu LTS kernel (3.11.x today), but is that necessary? Doesn't the latest 3.2 kernel contain newer drivers as well as ordinary bug fixes? (Noticeably, the Xubuntu team released 12.04.4 with the old 3.2 kernel instead for the updated 3.11.)

My uncertainty grew larger when I read about the Linux-firmware package. Maybe it is that instead of the kernel itself that is important?

I would be grateful if someone explains this quite plainly to me.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: Well... If you want! I can divide it into several.

Comment: Well... If you want! I can divide it into several. 1) Does the older suported LTS-kernels (3.2.x) also contain drivers for newer hardware? Or do I need to use a later supported LTS-kernel. (3.8.x or 3.11.x)

2) Is the package Linux-firmware involved in adding new drivers to the kernel according to Question 1?

3) If there is something more obvious (for you) that I have missed according to question 1&2, feel free to tell.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. I suggest you delete this question and post separately the three individual questions you mention above.

Comment: It is the same question. But the second version of it (rewritten on request) is easier to missunderstand according to what I want to know. It might give just those answers I already have, something I prefeer to avoid.

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the edit button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: Thakns for the information. I will have that in mind if I should find a reason to change the question. But so far i havn't.

Answer (score 1):

The Kernel is developed and maintained by linux foundation at [www.kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org).

Any kernel version will contain all bug fixes as long a it is supported(an all distros will upgrade to newer versions of kernel long before it's end of support)

But if certain hardware is not supported by x.y.z version, you will have to update to newer version.

If the current kernel version supports all your hardware, there is no need to install newer version  of kernel.You may unnecessarily break something that works!

Still, if you wish to install newer kernel, just update all your apps with`sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Thisis why i wrote a detailed question in first place. To avoid wrong answers.

IF IT DOES, well, the it should not be a problem.

But there is no way to know without benchmaarking everything. I don't like that idea.

Please read the full question before you are answering. I  saves your time as well.

Comment: Do you want to know what kernel is?Who develops it  & how?There are so many question marks that it makes things complex.

Comment: Wrong guessed again. If you want to answer, then you must also know what I already know. It is explained in a plain quite easy english. If it is to hard, please leave it to someone else. (No offence meant, sorry mate.)

Comment: english is not the problem, the formatting is.the title should explain the question in one sentence.If you still don't agree though, I may ask some more experienced person to look at this question and tell you if it's proper or not and if it's correct,he will give the answer.

Comment: Well. "Latest kernel" might mean different things in different contexts. If we are talking about the mainline, it is 3.13.2. I think this is the wrong way to understand it in this particular situation.

It might also mean any “latest kernel” at it's own supported level. Meaning the latest 3.2 kernel in the case of Ubuntu 12.04. This might be a more accurate way to understand “latest kernel” in this discussion.
I have found no answers to this from the vendor (Asus), or debian/ubuntu or internet at large. I'm no newbee with Linux, but I still don't know this.